# D3 elevation graph with fill based on slope

Tags: csv, d3.js, fill, elevation

I'm trying to create a filled line graph based on the gradients between points. I got a little help creating the fill, but I don't think I understand how it's determining which fill to use and how to move forward to get what I want. I'd like to have lines at 0, 4%, 7%, 10%, >12% and the negatives of those. I know there's a color function in d3, but I'm not sure how to work it in here. Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iyzVKRWpWqozCrGkkfkn?p=preview).

What I'm shooting for looks something like [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_em1o0CtR1yw/S-tOE1uJPCI/AAAAAAAAAAc/QY0l2ahfY_A/s1600/Map,%2BRas%2BRR,%2BElevation,%2BMapMyRide.JPG).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: url(#line-gradient);
    stroke: url(#line-gradient);
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.distance); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.elevation); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.distance = +d.distance;
        d.elevation = +d.elevation;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.distance; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.elevation; })]);


    svg.append("linearGradient")                
        .attr("id", "line-gradient")            
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")    


    .selectAll("stop")                      
        .data([                             
            {offset: "0%", color: "red"},       
            {offset: "4%", color: "red"},   
            {offset: "4%", color: "black"},     
            {offset: "6%", color: "black"},     
            {offset: "6%", color: "lawngreen"}, 
            {offset: "9%", color: "lawngreen"}  
        ])                  
    .enter().append("stop")         
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })   
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });

    // Add the valueline path.
    var maxX = x(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.distance; })[1]);
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line").attr("fill","url(#")
        .attr("d", ''+valueline(data)+"L0,"+y(0)+'L'+maxX+","+y(0));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've implemented something very close (if I understand what you want correctly) [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/euca/).

Comment: That looks close! As you can see from the link, I'm looking to determine the fill (from the line to the x-axis) between two points based on the slope of the line between the same two points. I can either do the calculation in JS or take from a csv value.

Comment: I guess doing it in JS would give you a little bit more flexibility.